# Background Image slow app down

Tags: android, image, imageview

Currently I am trying to set at the top of the activity an background image.
Specifications of the image:

Height: 290dp
Width: match_parent
ScaleType: cropCenter

The background image is stored in @drawables. The image has a size of 750 x 600 px.
It's 41,3 KB large.

The XML of my activity looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#E6E6E6">

<ImageView
    android:layout_height="290dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/background_rocket">

</ImageView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:paddingTop="240dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The result of the running application:
[image]

That's exactly what I want, but it's horrible slow (when I am running it on my S8). When I'm scrolling down, it stucks. When I am running it on the Android Studio Emulator it works fine (I think a bit slower as normal, but much better as on my real phone).

I already downloaded the plugin: Drawable Importer.

[image]

But it didn't help.

Notice: The custom `ListView Adapter` should be no problem, because when I remove the `ImageView` it runs smooth.

Comment: is there any difference if you change `android:background="#E6E6E6"` to `"@drawable/background_rocket"` ?

Comment: @pskink nope, still the same. But thanks.

Comment: @pskink yes, I'm using a custom `Adapater`. The content of the `GetView` method: `if(convertView == null)
                convertView = mContext.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_person, null); return convertView;`

Answer (score 1):

Add `ImageView` as `ListView`'s header .

Try this .

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_listview);
View headerView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.your_image,null);
listView.addHeaderView(headerView);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tryed it. Now there is something different. When I see the image it's stocking, but when the image is scrolled out, it works.

Comment: Because picture loading takes a little bit of time

Answer (score 1):

If your image with `750x600` resolution is in the `drawable-xxxhdpi` folder, the image will be scaled on your Samsung S8. Because your device has `1440x2960` pixels resolution.

Scaling process will increase the creation time process naturally and also will consume about **5 mb** from Memory, not **45 kb**.

Scaling small images to larger, causes memory issues(etc. OOM Exceptions) on some bigger screen devices.

And also your images on the ListView items will be scaled too. This scaling process may be the cause of laggy scrolling issue.

Note: Always use RecyclerView for better performance and more flexibility.
For image loading you can use **Glide** or **Picasso** libraries for more performance and better caching mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load image with any image loader like [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) or any other image loading library